# Does a dword store to a stack address affect bytes at address+0..3 or address-0..3?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, cpu-architecture, memory-address

- In the x86 architecture (say 32 bit) does an address point to just a single byte?  Meaning, if we looked at address 0x0000 0000 0000 FFFF is that just one byte?  I think the answer to this is yes, but would like confirmation

---

- I'd like to know how the values are stored for this instruction, `movl  %eax, -4(%rbp)`.  My understanding is we are putting the values on the stack at a lower address of the base pointer.

  Since eax is 32 bits, how does this actually show up on the stack when we do the operation?  Meaning, if eax has 0x0a0b0c0d, and using little endian is it this?

```
rbp[-4]   0d           ; low byte at given address
rbp[-3]   0c
rbp[-2]   0b
rbp[-1]   0a           ; dword ending here
```

OR this?

```
rbp[-7]   0d
rbp[-6]   0c
rbp[-5]   0b
rbp[-4]   0a          ; high byte at given address, dword ending here
```

OR
something else because I don't understand?  Any help would be great

Comment: Don't overthink it.  Loads & Stores always compute & work from the lowest (numerically) address of multi-byte memory data.  The stack growing downwards doesn't change that; negative displacement addressing doesn't change that.

Answer (score 4):

Every byte has its own address, so in that sense there is only one byte at address 0x12345678.  However, we commonly say things like "the doubleword at address 0x12345678".  This means the 4-byte doubleword formed by the bytes at addresses 0x12345678, 0x12345679, 0x1234567a, 0x1234567b, least significant first.

So it depends what you mean by "look at the address".  For instance, if you ask a debugger to display the contents of address 0x12345678, and it is set to display doublewords, it will show you a 4-byte doubleword, but that does not mean that all 4 bytes of that doubleword are at address 0x12345678.

As such, the first of your two guesses for `movl %eax, -4(%rbp)` is the correct one.  For loads and stores larger than one byte, **the given address points to the lowest-addressed byte of the object to be accessed.**

Note that this makes alignment calculation work well: an aligned dword is one where the address is a multiple of 4, so the low 2 bits of the dword address are zero.  In C terms `((uintptr_t)&intvar) % 4 == 0`, for alignof(int) == 4.  The other way would mean that the low n bits would have to be all-1 for an aligned object.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. Adressing granularity is **one byte**, so yes,  address `0x0000 0000 0000 FFFF` points to a byte, whose predecessor is addressed with `0x0000 0000 0000 FFFE` and whose successor is addressed with `0x0000 0000 0001 0000`. However, instead of one byte we could also load a 16bit word from the same address.
For instance, the instruction  `MOV AX,[0x0000_0000_0000_FFFF]` will load both AL from `0x0000 0000 0000 FFFF` and AH from `0x0000 0000 0001 0000`. In this case `0x0000 0000 0000 FFFF` is addressing **a word**. Similary, longer datatypes can be addressed with the same number (although aligning is always recommended and sometimes mandatory in this architecture).

If `EAX` contains the value  `0x0a0b0c0d`, then `AL=0x0D`, `AH=0x0C` etc.
`movl %eax, -4(%rbp)` alias `MOV [RBP-4],EAX` in Intel syntax, will store 32bit double word to an address `[RBP-4]`, i.e. `AL=0x0D` goes to `[RBP-4]`, `AH=0x0C` goes to `[RBP-3]` etc.